# Entity Framework - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having a hard time getting Entity Framework to do what I want it to do.  I've got a form generator application that's already up and fully running in .NET WebForms.  I've just begun the process of converting this over to use .NET MvC instead, with React as the view layer and Entity Framework to drive the database stuff.

One part of this application is intended to allow the users to add form controls to a list and have them laid out visually as they would be shown on the final published form.  So you click on First Name, and it adds an input control with ID FirstName, header text above it, etc.

I've got the view layer set up to show some basic info about the controls and put them into a list.  I've also already got all the database tables with the assembled information about various types of controls you can add to the page.  My WebForms version of this manages all the relationships between various data tables and how that is packaged for the view layer through code.

I've been trying to use my existing tables in Entity Framework but haven't been able to get any of the foreign key relationships to work correctly.  When I add them in MS SQL, they don't carry over and give me ways of accessing the data from the foreign tables via the objects representing a main table.

When I just leave the tables without any foreign key relationships in SQL itself 
and add them to the model in Visual Studio, it also won't sync up the objects correctly.  It will throw errors relating to missing mapping or that it can't find the data in the foreign objects.

So I've reached the point where I am importing all my tables, which does work correctly, but then I have to update the model for each table to add an object or collection of objects that can contain a reference to the corresponding matched foreign key data.  Then I have to write procedures which will go through and set the object references themselves according to ID columns which already exist in the database (ControlType in Controls table matches up to ID in ControlTypes table, etc.).

Then if I make a change in the database and update the model, it will remove all the custom objects I've added to the model, and possibly throw more errors to boot if I've removed a column on the database.  What a headache!

So I know that seems like a wall of text, but I'm at a loss for what to do.  I'd like to just have a big data object that I can pass around for each control that contains all the related info pertinent to that particular control and can be used by React in my view layer to display the info.

An alternative to that is I could build in Ajax requests into the various components which would make database calls to get the info relevant to that particular portion of the control, but that seems like a huge pain.

Am I going about this all wrong or is EF really just this hard to use?

Comment: EF works best when you let it do what IT wants to do.  Seems like you have a working solution, what are you gaining from wedging EF in?

Comment: Well, I've spent the last ten years as a solo developer and I guess I got used to living in a bubble.  I didn't pay that much attention to technology trends until the last year or two, to the point that I actually wrote my own ORM for my form generator without knowing about things like ActiveRecord or Entity Framework.

Comment: So coming to terms with the modern state of web development, I figure that these sophisticated systems written by huge companies should be the thing to go with, just let them handle all the database stuff that I wrote by hand for my form generator (as opposed to the database stuff it actually generates for finished forms, that's all performed automatically).

Comment: If EF isn't solving a problem, don't use it.  There are other ORMs, lighter micro-ORMS that do more of what you need and stay out of the way -- or don't use one.